# How to import an existing project on Magento 1.7 to my local workspace?

Tags: magento-1.7, import

I have tried to import an existing project on a web server of Magento 1.7 into my local web server xampp on windows, but it's been impossible.

I have all the files and folders on the project directory, and i also imported the database.

I have access to the dashboard, and i can see some features that are on the database, like for example, when i'm creating a page i can select a custom theme which information is in the database, with this, i can confirm that the magento installation on my web server is reading the database properly.

My problem is that i can't see any of the existing pages on the web server on my dashboard > CMS > Pages and i need to modify one of them, but i can't do it as i can't see it.

Could it be that i'm missing a configuration file?

I aprecciate any help you can offer me, i'm complete new in magento and i really need help with this.

If you need some more details about the installation or something in order to be able to answer, please feel free to do so, i will answer!

Thank you already!

Comment: have you changed `app/etc/local.xml` for database connection and `core_config_data` table with url

Answer (score 2):

Can you create new items, i.e. new CMS pages? If yes, the database import was incomplete and you should redo it. If no, there must be some kind of error message, either in the logs or in the HTML of the page if you uncomment the line `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in the `index.php`.